# Service Unavailable when I publish site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I develop a site using Asp.Net MVC. It worked on local. When I publish site, to the server,It gives below error:

```
Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503.
The service is unavailable.
```

When we call the hosting company, they set the problem and then site is beginning to work. I think, IIS pool is stopped ,and I don't know how it happens.
Why can this situation happen? Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the server to view the application pool settings?